# Hive keep using derby instead of mysql

Tags: java, mysql, hadoop, jdbc, hive

I'm new on using Hive, I got problem because at first I use derby and now I want to use mysql, but when I check the error log it still hitting the derby how to change from derby to mysql? thank you

I run this
`schematool -dbType mysql -initSchema --verbose`

but ends to have this

```
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/local/Cellar/hive/3.1.2_3/libexec/lib/log4j-slf4j-impl-2.10.0.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/3.3.1/libexec/share/hadoop/common/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.30.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLoggerFactory]
Metastore connection URL:    jdbc:derby:;databaseName=metastore_db;create=true
Metastore Connection Driver :    org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver
Metastore connection User:   APP
Starting metastore schema initialization to 3.1.0
Initialization script hive-schema-3.1.0.mysql.sql
Connecting to jdbc:derby:;databaseName=metastore_db;create=true
Connected to: Apache Derby (version 10.14.1.0 - (1808820))
Driver: Apache Derby Embedded JDBC Driver (version 10.14.1.0 - (1808820))
Transaction isolation: TRANSACTION_READ_COMMITTED
0: jdbc:derby:> !autocommit on
Autocommit status: true
0: jdbc:derby:> /*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */
Error: Syntax error: Encountered "<EOF>" at line 1, column 64. (state=42X01,code=30000)
Closing: 0: jdbc:derby:;databaseName=metastore_db;create=true
org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaException: Schema initialization FAILED! Metastore state would be inconsistent
```

I already change the hive-site.xml but it still the same

```
   <property>
      <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionURL</name>
      <value>jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.01:3306/metastore?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true&useSSL=false</value>
      <description>metadata is stored in a MySQL server</description>
   </property>
```

Thank you very much for your help

Answer (score 0):

There are 3 modes of running the hive Metastore :

1. Embedded Metastore
2. Local Metastore
3. Remote Metastore

Embedded Metastore always runs with an embedded derby database.

If you wish to run with MySQL, you will need to use local Metastore or remote Metastore mode ([refer here for more details of each mode](https://data-flair.training/blogs/apache-hive-metastore/))

Also note, you will have to set the correct JDBC driver in hive-site.xml as well.

```
 <property>
    <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionDriverName</name>
    <value>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</value>
</property>
```